# How find all the items of a list which are not in a generic list with multiple condition

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-3.5

I have a list "A" and a generic list "B". I need to find all the items of "A" those are not in "B" with multiple condition.

List "A":

```
EXWORK
CENTAGES
PREMIUM
```

List "B":

```
PARTICULARS   CATAGORY   DETAIL
EXWORK        ERECTION     ABC
CENTAGES      ERECTION     ABC
PREMIUM       SUPPLY       ABC
```

For this I use following code:

```
var value = A.Where(a => B.All(b => b.CATAGORY == "SUPPLY" && b.PARTICULARS!=a));
```

but this return the value "Premium" also whereas it shouldn't be. I am not figuring out where I am making mistake.

My Desired result is:

```
EXWORK
CENTAGES
```

Comment: Hi Sonu, Welcome to the stackoverflow. We would like to see [reprex], where you can try out and solve your query. It is really difficult for us to look at image and analyse Linq and identify problem in it. I would also encourage you to go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) documentation which explains you how to ask a good question

Comment: You claim you want to find all items of `A` that are _not_ in `B`; and yet, you want both `EXWORK` and `CENTAGES` returned? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Sorry @AstridE. edited.

Comment: I still find it difficult to understand exactly what you need, but hopefully one of the provided answers will be something you can use?

Comment: @sonu If you want `EXWORK` and `CENTAGES` why do you have the condition `b.CATAGORY == "SUPPLY"`? Could you try explain the rule you are looking for in words?

Comment: Perhaps what you want is something more like: `A.Where(a => B.Where(b => b.CATAGORY == "SUPPLY").All(b => b.PARTICULARS != a)`

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to find all items in `A` that are *not* listed as a `PARTICULAR` categorized as `SUPPLY` in `B`?

If so, you could find all items in `B` where `CATEGORY = "SUPPLY"` and return list `A` except the `PARTICULAR` values of the filtered `B` items.

```csharp
var value = A.Except(
    B.Where(b => b.CATAGORY == "SUPPLY")
        .Select(b => b.PARTICULARS));
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mRpsyL).

Comment: I don't think `Except` is appropriate since `A` and `B` are not the same type.

Comment: `A` and `B` are not the same type, but `A` and `B.Select(b => b.PARTICULARS)` are. Unless I've misinterpreted something.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you mean:

```
var value = A.Where(a => !B.Any(b => b.CATAGORY == "SUPPLY" && b.PARTICULARS == a));
```

Comment: Please look at my desired result(edited).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your query, you are trying to filter list `A` based on the condition from List `B` i.e `b.CATAGORY == "SUPPLY"` and `PARTICULARS` should be present in `A` list.

To get desire output, you have iterate though List `B` and filter records based on condition `b.CATAGORY == "SUPPLY"` and `PARTICULARS` property,

```
var result = B
    .Where(x => x.CATAGORY == "ERECTION" && A.Contains(x.PARTICULARS))  //Use Contains.
    .Select(x => x.PARTICULARS);  //Select only PARTICULARS value.
```

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TGpccd)

---

If you want data from List `A`, then you can break your linq in two steps,

```
var resultB = B
    .Where(x => x.CATAGORY == "SUPPLY")
    .Select(x => x.PARTICULARS).ToList();

var value = A.Except(resultB);
```

Comment: Sorry @Prasad there was a correction, I've edited.

Comment: Now you just need to replace `SUPPY` with `ERECTION`

Comment: I may be having the wrong impression, but OP says they need items of `A`; I'd say you'd need `A.Except( <your expression> )`? -- which I was just about to post myself.

Comment: I don't think so. He just want data of `PARTICULAR` which satisfies given condition. Is that true @Sonu?

Comment: @AstridE., I updated my question with alternate solution to get data from List A. with `Intersect()`.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Perhaps I read your answer too quickly, or before your first edit -- and then drew conclusions too quickly. Anyways, we don't know exaclty what OP wants; I find their example input/output does not show exclusively how the filtering should happen.

Comment: I agree with you @AstridE.

Comment: I need all the items of "A" those not available in "B" but search only the rows where category is "SUPPLY" in "B".

Comment: @Sonu, I updated my answer to support `SUPPLY` as a filter condition